# script tag is not appending in footer on ajax success

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, typescript

I am calling an ajax function and on success I need to create one script tag and it has few parameter and it's value into it. and finally I need to append this into footer.

My code is here

```
$.ajax({
    url:"ajaxcalls",
    type:"POST",
    data:{"call":"getThis","id":myID},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
        var po = document.createElement('script');
        po.type = 'text/javascript';
        po.defer = true;
        po.innerHTML = "hi";
        $("footer").append(po);
    },
    error:function(){}
});
```

My html should read like this as a output of this. I already have footer tag

```
<footer>
    //many js included
    <script type="text/javascript">hi</script>
</footer>
```

but on success, nothing is happening. I am unable to find the script in my footer. And it is not inside html either.

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX request is indeed resolving correctly?

Comment: I am sorry but i didn't exactly get your question